# CoreData Error: Invalid generation token: this persistent store coordinator does not have any of the referenced stores

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm unable to repro this error but my crash reporter indicates that it's fairly frequent among my users (iOS 12):

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 ***"A Core Data error occurred." UserInfo={Reason=Invalid generation token: this persistent store coordinator does not have any of the referenced stores***}: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang_Fall2018/swiftlang_Fall2018-1000.11.42/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 184

Crashing line example:

```
let result = try! self.syncContext.fetch(request)
```

I would like to decipher error message. Does ***Invalid generation token*** refers to [NSQueryGenerationToken](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsquerygenerationtoken)? Is the error part of conflict resolution process?

Comment: I'd guess it's more related to how you've setup you persistent store coordinator, and what PSC the `syncContext` is connected to. Can you supply any of that information, or code samples?

Comment: Hi @AndrewTetlaw, basically I've used this [sample code](https://github.com/objcio/core-data) as a reference. The crash is occuring in [this](https://github.com/objcio/core-data/blob/master/Moody/MoodySync/SyncCoordinator.swift#L178) line and [here](https://github.com/objcio/core-data/blob/master/SharedCode/Managed.swift#L88)